# How to generate a list of numbers with duplicates base on a certain seed in python

Tags: python, quicksort

I don't know how to generate a list of numbers with duplicates based on a certain seed.

I have tried using the code below, but it cannot generate numbers that have duplicates

```
random.seed(3340)
test = random.sample(range(100), 100000)
```

I think this could work, but I got an error saying "ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative"

I could implement some functions that can do this, but I think it would be a great idea if I can use some libraries.

Answer (score 2):

`random.sample` samples without replacement. `random.choices` samples with replacement, which is what you want:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: random.choices([1, 2], k=10)
Out[2]: [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

You can also do this with numpy:

```
In [3]: import numpy

In [4]: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
Out[4]:
array([7, 6, 3, 3, 8, 5, 9, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 8, 2, 4, 3, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 6,
       2, 3, 5, 8, 4, 9, 3, 3, 0, 8, 4, 4, 7, 2, 8, 4, 4, 9, 1, 1, 7, 1,
       3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7, 5, 1, 9, 6, 0, 4, 8, 9, 9, 4, 7, 6, 0, 5, 1, 8,
       4, 8, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 0, 2, 6, 4, 4, 2, 3, 0, 6, 7, 3, 5, 9, 3, 7,
       4, 1, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 0, 5, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you're looking for a simpler solution, but you could use indexing in a generator:

```
population = list(range(100))
sample = [population[random.randint(0,99) for _ in range(100000)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this comprehension as well:

```
random.seed(3340)
test = [random.randrange(100) for _ in  range(100000)]
```